# TimePicker crashes app when getting the minute and hour

Tags: java, c#, android, calendar, alarm

I am trying to get the `selected values` of the `hour` and `minute` from the `timePicker`, and then get the current `system time` from the user's device. Afterwards I need to `subtract` the `time selected - time.now` and then display to the user, the time remaining until the alarm goes ringing.

However the app is crashing, and I couldn't find an understanding.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void onClickAlarmOn(View v) {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePicker alarm_time_picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    int hour = alarm_time_picker.getHour(); //get selected hour
    int minute = alarm_time_picker.getMinute(); //get selected minute

    int hour_now = c.get(Calendar.HOUR); //get system's hour
    int minute_now = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); //get system's minute

    int hour_result = hour - hour_now; //subtract the time selected by time.now of system
    int minute_result = minute - minute_now;

    String hour_result_string = String.valueOf(hour_result); //convert to string to display
    String minute_result_string = String.valueOf(minute_result);

    setToast_result("Alarm set to " + hour_result_string + " hours " + minute_result_string + " minutes");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: which device you used and which api version in the device.

Comment: @Harshad I have tested on Samsung Galaxy S5 with API version 21, and also on Bluestacks with API version 19. Thanks!

Comment: change the device to `marshmallow` API 23. it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I run your code in `Lollipop Device` but same as your output `App is crash.`

then I read the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html

in Api 23

## Just For Information.

`getCurrentHour()`

This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use **getHour()**

`getCurrentMinute()`

This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use **getMinute()**

Now I change the Device And Run in `MarshMallow` it's working fine.

## Use code this way :

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePicker alarm_time_picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);



alarm_time_picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    
    int hour = alarm_time_picker.getHour(); //get selected hour
    int minute = alarm_time_picker.getMinute();


int hour_now = c.get(Calendar.HOUR); //get system's hour
int minute_now = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); //get system's minute

int hour_result = hour - hour_now; //subtract the time selected by time.now of system
int minute_result = minute - minute_now;

String hour_result_string = String.valueOf(hour_result); //convert to string to display
String minute_result_string = String.valueOf(minute_result);

setToast_result("Alarm set to " + hour_result_string + " hours " + minute_result_string + " minutes");

}
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer! For those who may have the same problem in the future: I have installed several API version of from the Android SDK Manager, so it matches my device version. Then I have right clicked on the app folder structure, Open Module Settings and on the 'flavors' tab, chose an older version in the minimum sdk.